# В чём отличие репликации и синхронизации, применительно к базам данных?

Tags: база-данных, синхронизация, репликация

В чём отличие репликации и односторонней синхронизации, применительно к базам данных? Вот то, что я нашла [по поводу репликации](https://habrahabr.ru/post/56702/):

> Репликация (от лат. replico -повторяю) — это тиражирование изменений
>   данных с главного сервера БД на одном или нескольких зависимых
>   серверах. Главный сервер будем называть мастером, а зависимые —
>   репликами.

и [по поводу односторонней синхронизации](http://www.handybackup.ru/synchronizacia-mysql.shtml):

> Односторонняя синхронизация. Содержимое одной базы (master) копируется
>   в другую базу (slave). В MySQL синхронизация баз данных на разных
>   серверах используется для репликации таблиц, создания тестовых и
>   резервных баз, бэкапа MySQL и т.д

По этим определениям похоже, что эти понятия значат одно и то же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Синхронизация данных — ликвидация различий между двумя копиями данных.
>   Предполагается, что ранее эти копии были одинаковы, а затем одна из
>   них, либо обе были независимо изменены.
>
> Репликация — это процесс, под которым понимается копирование данных из
>   одного источника на другой (или на множество других) и наоборот.

В контексте данного конкретного примера - это одно и то же. В более широком смысле - эти понятия означают разные процессы.

**UPD**

Синхронизация - это цель. Репликация - способ ее достижения.

Можно произвести синхронизацию без репликации. Надуманный пример: необходимо в двух БД синхронизировать таблицу, содержащую числа от 1 до 100. Репликация тут применима, но можно вполне обойтись и без нее.

Можно использовать репликацию, целью которой не будет синхронизация данных. Например на табличке висит триггер, умножающий каждое INSERT'нутое поле на два. Репликация будет - синхронизация не очень.

Comment: а в каком случае эти понятия означают разные процессы? очень хотелось бы увидеть пример

Comment: @Ksenia например я могу синхронизировать мои и ваши часы. Ровно через 20 секунд выставим на них 20:15:11

Comment: а какое отношение этот пример имеет к базам данных? :)

Comment: @Ksenia собственно я же не зря писал, что "В контексте данного конкретного примера - это одно и то же". Что же до отвлеченных размышлений, то обновил ответ.